# Showing that a nonlinear functional is bounded

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I am working on the following problem:

Suppose $E$ is the set of real-valued functions continuous on $[a,b]$ such that $|\int_a^b f dx | \leq 1$ and $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq|x-y|^{1/2}$ for each $x,y\in[a,b]$. Consider the functional $$\lambda(f) = \int_a^b (1-5x^2) f^{10} dx.$$ Is $\lambda$ bounded on $E$ and if so, does it attain its maximum and minimum on $E$?

This is a variant of a question for my department's analysis qualifying exam. I'm not sure on how one is supposed to go about this. I can show that $\lambda$ is bounded as long as $f$ is given but the only results I know about proving boundedness are for linear operators (uniform boundedness principle, etc.).

What are some other things I could try? I tried skimming through some textbooks and couldn't find anything that seemed helpful. Any suggestions would be immensely appreciated!

Comment: I think the approach here would be to try to show that $\lambda$ is continuous for the sup norm, and then that $E$ is compact (using Arzela-Ascoli for example).

Comment: Oh! Upon first inspection, this seems promising. I haven't heard of this result before. I'll give it a try. Thank you!